# Retrofit returning only 200 OK on push and put

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

Im trying to send JSON messages through HTTP with retrofit2 in android, to a django server with the rest api running.

using a retrofit interface and the calls:

```
@POST("getDates/")
Call<Event> newEvent(@Body Event event);

@PUT("getDates/{id}/")
Call<Event> updateEvent(@Path("id") int id, @Body Event event);
```

as well as

```
public void postNewEvent(Event event) {
    Call<Event> call = service.newEvent(event);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Event> call, Response<Event> response) {
            Log.i("REST", "POST was sucessful: " + response.isSuccessful());
            Log.i("REST", "response body: " + response.body().toString());
            Log.i("REST", "response message: " + response.message());
            Log.i("REST", "response code: " + response.code());
            Log.i("REST", "response code: " + response.errorBody());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Event> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("REST", t.getMessage());
            Log.e("REST", call.toString());
        }
    });
}

public boolean updateEvent(Event event) {
        Call<Event> call = service.updateEvent(event.getId(), event);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Event> call, Response<Event> response) {
                success = response.isSuccessful();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Event> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("REST", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

However, every message i send to the server through my interface only gets a reply with: OK and code:200. 
I have tried sending the calls manually through the api and it works just fine.
This code used to also work for me, but now it just stopped.
I've added an Nginx Server and Gunicorn instead of UWSGI, but i can't imagine them blocking the app.

Does anyone have a clue what could be going wrong? I just can't figure it out!

Comment: can you test the deployed api in post man?

Comment: yea, i did and it works fine.
I also deployed it on a test server, where it also works without a problem!

Does the base_URI have to be an ip? Otherwise it must be the server that im trying to connect to, sending me strange replies